# Error while updating a date column using SQL*Plus variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am not able to update the date time which I have already stored in a variable and I am trying to update the another record with date time present in that variable.

```
last_update_time=`sqlplus -s user/password@prpx1-vip.unix.gsm1900.org:7779/prpx.unix.gsm1900.org  <<!
set heading off;
set pagesize 0;

select to_char(last_update_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
from subs_change
where sub_id=$1 and value=$activerateplan and change_type='R';`

echo "Last Update Time for RatePlan$activerateplan is $last_update_time"
```

"Above code is storing the value in last_update_time variable."

```
update_records=`sqlplus -s user/password@prpx1-vip.unix.gsm1900.org:7779/prpx.unix.gsm1900.org  <<!
set heading off;
set pagesize 0;

update subs_change
set valid_to='$last_update_time'
where sub_id='$1' and value='$issue_rate_plan'
```

While trying to update date time using variable `$last_update_time` it's giving me an error.

Comment: What is the error? Can you view the value of $last_update_time before the SQL is sent to the server?

Comment: value of $last_update_time is like 06/22/2015 08:08:52.

Comment: And what is the result of SELECT CURRENT_DATE(); (not sure of Oracle syntax for this - use Oracle's syntax for NOW(); or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your to_char() date format doesn't match your database default format so it can't automatically convert it back to a date during the update.

Try something like the following:

```
update subs_change
set valid_to=to_date('$last_update_time','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
where sub_id='$1' and value='$issue_rate_plan';
```

This will explicitly convert your date string to an Oracle date type.

Comment: I tried this way, but I got error like "Invalid Month"